# Kotlin coroutineScope supposed to call all async functions concurrently

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I am new to Kotlin and [coroutines](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/coroutines-basics.html#scope-builder-and-concurrency).

I have the below code:

```
  fun asyncCallForRelationIdList(relationIds: List<String>): List<Any?> = runBlocking {
    println("Starting asynchronous code flow")
    asyncCallForUserIdList(relationIds)
  }

  suspend fun asyncCallForUserIdList(userIds: List<String>): List<Any?> = coroutineScope {
    println("Elements in list are supposed to call api concurrently")
    val listval = mutableListOf<Any?>()
    val result0 = async {restApiCall(relationId = userIds[0])}
    val result1 = async {restApiCall(relationId = userIds[1])}
    listval.add(result0.await())
    listval.add(result1.await())
    listval.toList()
  }

  suspend fun restApiCall(relationId: String): Any? {
    println("api call... the api will timeout with an artificial delay")
    //api call
    //return "api result"
  }
```

`asyncCallForRelationIdList()` function will call `asyncCallForUserIdList()` which then makes an API call that will timeout.

My question is about the `async` keyword that I am using in `coroutineScope`. I expect the 2 async calls to happen concurrently. But that is not the case here. After the first api call, the thread waits for the service to timeout instead of making the 2nd api call concurrently. Why?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55664109/is-there-asyncall-and-or-awaitall-operators-for-kotlin-coroutines

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/launch-vs-async-in-kotlin-coroutines, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46226518/what-is-the-difference-between-launch-join-and-async-await-in-kotlin-coroutines

Comment: Change your async calls to `async(Dispatchers.IO) { ... }` because they're not actually asynchronous, currently they're running in the scope of `runBlocking`.

Comment: How is your `restApiCall()` implemented? Your example should work as you expect, in parallel. But only assuming that `restApiCall()` was implemented properly, so it doesn't block the thread. If it blocks (my guess) then you need to fix its implementation to make it suspend instead.

Comment: @Pawel Yes this has solved the issue. Thanks.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/kotlin/coroutines/coroutines-adv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your async calls to async(Dispatchers.IO) { ... } because they're not actually asynchronous, currently they're running in the scope of runBlocking

Thanks to @Pawel

Answer (score 0):

you are using **runBlocking** so its will block the main thread and run one by one. and its not **Starting asynchronous code flow**.